# NullRefrenceException using reflection in the view and custom attributes on the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, reflection

I am getting a `NullReferenceException` in the following scenario

Test class:

```
[Order(0)]
public class Test
{
    [DisplayName("District Code")]
    [Editable(false)]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int DistrictCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error")]
    [Editable(false)]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Order(2)]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

Custom Order Attribute:

```
public class Order : Attribute
{
    public int Display { get; set; }
    public int Edit { get; set; }
    public int Create { get; set; }

    public Order(int all)
    {
        this.Display = all;
        this.Edit = all;
        this.Create = all;
    }
}
```

And I have the following foreach loop (Unrelated code removed for brevity):

```
@foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties()
         .Where(x => !x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HiddenInputAttribute)).Any()))
{
    prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Order), True)
        .GetType().GetProperty("Edit").GetValue(prop);
}
```

When I QuickWatch `prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Order), True).GetType()` I get what I expect. But if I QuickWatch `prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Order), True).GetType().GetProperty("Edit")` I get `null` back.

Why is can reflection not find the property `Edit` or could this actually be a different problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was I was getting `.GetCustomAttributes()` plural. So the `.GetType().GetProperty()` wasn't on `Order` but rather `Order[]` which does not contain the property `Edit` therefor it was null. So with a little help from Linq, it is now working. For those coming in here from google, my solution was the following:

```
@foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(x => !x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HiddenInputAttribute)).Any())
    .OrderBy(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Order), true)
    .Select(y => y.GetType().GetProperty("Edit").GetValue(y)).Single()))
```

Which I'm sure can be simplified and shortened, but it's a good start.